Deferring `magit` load without breaking highlight in `git-commit`
I am interacting with git via a set of zsh functions/aliases I've grown over the years, so I don't typically need magit. In fact, I only have magit installed to provide syntax highlight for when git commit invokes an editor.
A few weeks ago I used use-package to measure startup time, and found that magit takes around half a second, which more than everything else I have, despite being there just for syntax highlight.
Now, I know use-package has :defer t to defer a package from loading. The problem though is that deferring magit results in syntax highlight getting lost inside git-commit. I spent some time digging through magit, but I'm still not quite sure what the highlight is hooked up to, and how to have it without loading everything.
So, how can I defer magit but still get git commit syntax highlight?
Steps to reproduce

Load magit with (use-package magit :defer t …
Save the following text to COMMIT_EDITMSG
.gitignore:
# comment
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   .gitignore
#
# Untracked files:
#   foo.js
#
# Everything below it will be ignored.
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
index 30efe19..fe25baa 100644
--- a/.gitignore
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-/foo/
+/bar/


Open emacs COMMIT_EDITMSG

Expected
The text is highlighted
Actual
The text has no highlight.

Do you start a new emacs for each commit, or do you use server-mode?

I tried (use-package magit :defer t :init (require 'git-commit)) but my configuration is a bit messy so it didn't quite work.  Might be something worth trying on a clean emacs setup?

@choroba I use server-mode/emacsclient, but sometimes I still need to restart Emacs fully. Typically, when I modify some mode and I want to see if everything is alright before sending a pull-request. In these cases having faster restarts is still desired.

@Winny it probably needs to go after :config because putting it after :init results in "void symbol magit-process-git" error. But no, using this line (with :config in place of :init) doesn't make syntax highlight to work.

This is documented in the FAQ entry git-commit-mode isn’t used when committing from the command-line).
;; Expensive:
(require 'git-commit)
;; or cheaper, but you have to keep the path up-to-date:
;; (load "/path/to/magit-autoloads.el")

(use-package server
  :config (unless (server-running-p) (server-mode)))

A note on using (use-package magit ...): Despite what its docstring says, use-package's NAME argument refers to a "feature" not a "package". The feature you are interested in here is git-commit, which is provided by the git-commit.el library. I.e., you want (use-package git-commit). (But if you don't add any additional arguments, then that is just a slightly more expensive and verbose way of doing (require 'git-commit).
